# Grails 3.1.6, Hibernate 4. Composite foreign key

Tags: hibernate, grails, foreign-keys, grails-orm, composite-primary-key

```
class Tooth {
  Integer id
  ToothDisease toothDisease
   static mapping = {
    table name: 'AK_TOOTH'
    id generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'SEQ_AK_TOOTH']
    columns{
        toothDisease {
        column: 'FK_AK_TOOTH_ID' 
        column: 'FK_AK_TOOTH_NR_VERSION' 
        }
    }
} 
class ToothDisease implements Serializable{
  Integer idColumn
  Integer nrVersion
   static mapping = {
    table name: 'AK_TOOTH_DISEASE'
    idColumn column: 'ID', generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'SEQ_AK_TOOTH_DISEASE']
    nrVersion  column: 'NR_VERSION',
    id composite ['idColumn','nrVersion']

   int hashCode () {
    def builder = new HashCodeBuilder ()
    builder.append (idColumn)
    builder.append (nrVersion)
    builder.toHashCode ()
  }

  boolean equals (other) {
    if (other == null) {
      return false
    }
    def builder = new EqualsBuilder ()
    builder.append (idColumn, other.idColumn)
    builder.append (nrVersion, other.nrVersion)
    builder.isEquals ()
  }
}
```

When I try to bootRun my app I get BeanCreationException:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK_1rnajvolkf4rkav5w1hl0l9fk:AK_TOOTH [tooth_disease_id,FK_AK_TOOTH_ID,FK_AK_TOOTH_NR_VERSION,tooth_disease_id_column,tooth_disease_nr_version])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (AK_TOOTH_DISEASE [ID,NR_VERSION]).
```

When I removed column mapping section in Tooth, then I got the same error without those columns

```
[tooth_disease_id,tooth_disease_id_column,tooth_disease_nr_version].
```

Is it possible to explicitly define key column and referencedColumnName like in hibernate?
Why there are three columns? especially `tooth_disease_id and tooth_disease_id_column columns` in the same time. I tried to use 'primaryKey' name as composite primary key for Tooth and 'id' simple as id column, but in this way, I had the same error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK_1rnajvolkf4rkav5w1hl0l9fk:AK_TOOTH [tooth_disease_id,FK_AK_TOOTH_ID,FK_AK_TOOTH_NR_VERSION,tooth_disease_id_column,tooth_disease_nr_version])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (AK_TOOTH_DISEASE [ID]).But there is only one referenced primary key.
```

Unfortunately, I have no chance to change schema structure and avoid composite key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Composite-foreign-key-tp3046351p3046436.html)  the workaround from Burt Beckwith. 
Since GrailsAnnotationConfiguration was replaced by HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.groovy I made some changes in his solution:

```
class CompositeForeignKeyConfiguration extends HibernateMappingContextConfiguration {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1
  private static final String TOOTH_CLASS_NAME = 'com.project.TOOTH'
    private static final String TOOTH_ID_FK = 'FK_AK_TOOTH_ID'
  private static final String TOOTH_VERSION_FK = 'FK_AK_TOOTH_NR_VERSION'

  private boolean _alreadyProcessed

  @SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
  @Override
  protected void secondPassCompile () throws MappingException {

    for (PersistentEntity pc : hibernateMappingContext.getPersistentEntities ()) {
      if (pc.name == TOOTH_CLASS_NAME) {
        pc.getAssociations ().each { Association mp ->
          if (mp.name == 'toothDisease') {
            PropertyConfig config = (PropertyConfig) mp.getMapping ().getMappedForm ()
            if (config.columns.size () == 1) {
              config.columns.clear ()
              final ColumnConfig fk1 = new ColumnConfig (name: TOOTH_ID_FK )
              final ColumnConfig fk2 = new ColumnConfig (name: TOOTH_VERSION_FK )
              config.columns << fk1
              config.columns << fk2
            }
          }
        }
      }

    }

    super.secondPassCompile ()
    if (_alreadyProcessed) {
      return
    }
    _alreadyProcessed = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is caused by the way you are declaring the FK to ToothDisease in Tooth's mapping.

Try this:

```
class Tooth {
   Integer id
   ToothDisease toothDisease

   static mapping = {
      table name: 'AK_TOOTH'
      id generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'SEQ_AK_TOOTH']
      toothDisease {
          column name: 'FK_AK_TOOTH_ID' 
          column name: 'FK_AK_TOOTH_NR_VERSION' 
      }
   }

} 

class ToothDisease implements Serializable{
   Integer idColumn
   Integer nrVersion

   static mapping = {
       table name: 'AK_TOOTH_DISEASE'
       idColumn column: 'ID', generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'SEQ_AK_TOOTH_DISEASE']
       nrVersion  column: 'NR_VERSION'
       id composite: ['idColumn','nrVersion']
   }

   int hashCode () {
       def builder = new HashCodeBuilder ()
       builder.append (idColumn)
       builder.append (nrVersion)
       builder.toHashCode ()
   }

    boolean equals (other) {
       if (other == null) {
          return false
       }
       def builder = new EqualsBuilder ()
       builder.append (idColumn, other.idColumn)
       builder.append (nrVersion, other.nrVersion)
       builder.isEquals ()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it didn`t help me.  Still the same error with three column for foreign key.